# Swift 5- how to put image from assets folder into JSON file and load into viewcontroller

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I have a set of images in my assets folder and i have a JSON file that is stored in XCode. I am pulling the data from the JSON file to show in the detailviewcontroller of mydirectory application. I want to also use the images for the people in the directory but I am unsure of how to properly put the images in the JSONfile and how to load those into the viewcontroller when they user is clicked on the tablview.

Example of JSON:

```
    {
        "firstName": "Shemsi",
        "lastName": "Alhaddad",
        "office": "Founders Hall 201",
        "phone": "803-313-7446",
        "bio": "Associate Professor of Mathematics and Statistics",
        "email": "alhaddad@mailbox.sc.edu"
        "image": "cindy_kirk.jpeg"
    },
```

Example of what I have found from researching how to do this:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                self?.image = image
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

I am currently unsure if this will work due to my photos being in the assets folder and the JSON being in the app. I am getting all my information for the details of the users with this function:

```
private func parseJSON() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "UserData", ofType: "json") else {
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dataFromJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserData].self, from: jsonData)
            
            self.userDataArray = dataFromJSON
            
            print("success")
        }
        catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is "my assets folder"? You don't mean an Asset Catalog do you? If so just fetch by name with `image(named:)`.

Comment: Or are you saying the images are online and you need to download them on demand? In that case, this is a well studied matter and you should search.

Comment: I am sorry, When i say assets folder i am referencing assets.xcassets. And no the images are not online. I have found a lot showing how to download them from online but i am not sure how to make them fetch the appropriate image by name when the users are in the JSON file. would I need to store the title of the image with the corresponding user in the file at all?

Comment: You cannot just put images randomly into `asset.xcassets` as if it were just any kind of folder. It's an asset catalog. It has a structure, json files, folders, etc. That structure gives the images names. You can see the names just by opening the asset catalog with Xcode. If you cannot see them, you have not stored the images in the asset catalog at all.

Comment: I can see the image names when i click on the folder. I can see the image when i click on the name. I just want to load the image into the UIImage when i click on the usersname from the tableview i have already loaded them into. I am just unsure how to have that specific image show up when i click on the name. I am unsure if i am explaining this correctly

Comment: @MattyJay94 - to clarify... Are you saying that when you build the app, you have already added all of the "user images" to your asset catalog? If so... you show this as part of your json data: `"image": "cindy_kirk.jpeg"` ... so, if you have that image in your catalog, it will (by default) be named `cindy_kirk`. To load it at runtime,  use `UIImage(named: str)` where `str` is "cindy_kirk.jpeg" with the `.jpeg` part stripped off.

Comment: Okay. I see what you are saying and i think I got it figured out. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: That is the same as what I said right at the start, right? Remember I said, "you just fetch with `UIImage(named:)`...?"